# EC2Config Cloudwatch logs streaming not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I was hoping someone could help with this, I'm trying to stream logs from a Windows Server 2012 with EC2config service installed.

I have followed the following documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-cloudwatch-logs-with-amazon-ec2-running-microsoft-windows-server/

Unfortunately nothing is streaming to cloudwatch logs.

Here is the Json I'm using:

```
{
"EngineConfiguration": {
    "PollInterval": "00:00:15",
    "Components": [
        {
            "Id": "ApplicationEventLog",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "LogName": "Application",
                "Levels": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "SystemEventLog",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "LogName": "System",
                "Levels": "7"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "SecurityEventLog",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
            "LogName": "Security",
            "Levels": "7"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "ETW",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "LogName": "Microsoft-Windows-WinINet/Analytic",
                "Levels": "7"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "IISLog",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.IISLogOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
        "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC1"
        "AccessKey": "",
        "SecretKey": "",
        "Region": "eu-west-1",
        "LogGroup": "Web-Logs",
        "LogStream": "IIStest"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "CustomLogs",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\CustomLogs\\",
                "TimestampFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                "Encoding": "UTF-8",
                "Filter": "",
                "CultureName": "en-US",
                "TimeZoneKind": "Local"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "PerformanceCounter",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "CategoryName": "Memory",
                "CounterName": "Available MBytes",
                "InstanceName": "",
                "MetricName": "Memory",
                "Unit": "Megabytes",
                "DimensionName": "",
                "DimensionValue": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
                "AccessKey": "",
                "SecretKey": "",
                "Region": "eu-west-1",
                "LogGroup": "Win2Test",
                "LogStream": "logging-test"
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "CloudWatch",
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": 
            {
                "AccessKey": "",
                "SecretKey": "",
                "Region": "eu-west-1",
                "NameSpace": "Windows/Default"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Flows": {
        "Flows": 
        [
            "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs",
    "IISLog"
        ]
    }
} 
}
```

At this moment in time i only want to stream the IIS logs, from my understanding the Cloudwatch Log group and stream should automatically create.

Comment: Does your instance have an instance profile that grants it access via a role to cloud watch groups / s3 buckets for logs?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with Flows section is the second component of Flow definition is missing :

instead of

```
"Flows": {
    "Flows": 
    [
        "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs",
"IISLog"
    ]
}
```

It should be

```
    [
        "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs",
        "IISLog,CloudWatchLogs"
    ]
```

The `Flows` section defines the source and target of the  components from `Components` section first being what/how to get and second is how to send. 
e.g. consider following snippet here `ApplicationEventLog` and `SystemEventLog` will be sent to `CloudWatch` (refers to `"Id" : "CloudWatch"` defined in `Components` instead of AWS CloudWatch).

The second line defines second flow i.e. `PerformanceCounter` sent to `CloudWatch1`

```
    "Flows": {
        "Flows": 
        [
            "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs",
            "PerformanceCounter,CloudWatch1"
        ]
    }
```

hope this explains how it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i made a few mistakes on the JSON file itself, specifically the FLOW area.

Got this working now :)

Comment: Any chance you can be more specific?